# How to use @Resource Annotation when there are multiple class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

Here is my interface:

```
public interface Shape{
    public int size();
}
```

And the two classes implementing it:

```
@Repository("Circle")
public class Circle implements Shape
{
       public int size()
       {
             //code
             return size;
       }
}
```

And

```
@Repository("Square")
public class Square implements Shape
{
       public int size()
       {
             //code
             return size;
       }
}
```

Now, can I use the following code?

```
public class MyTest
{
       @Resource(name="Circle")
       Shape circle;
       @Resource(name="Square")
       Shape square;
       public int size()
       {
             int size = circle.size() + square.size();//Is this correct?
             return size;
       }
}
```

For some reason my code is giving me null pointer exception, perhaps is there another way to tell the resource annotation which sub-class I wanted to use? (Should I be using other annotation instead??)

Comment: Show us the code that uses the `MyTest` bean

Comment: Are you sure that your packages being scanned and beans are registered?

Comment: @Qualifier annotation no?

Comment: I just use a main to call the function inside MyTest.